# pentaho database join error to match input data

Tags: pentaho

I have an input.csv file in which I have field "id" .
I need to do a database lookup with below logic.

I need to search whether the "id" is present in the field "supp_text"and extract the field "loc_id".

Eg, 
id = 12345.
and, in my supp_text, I have the value "the value present is 12345".

I am using "Database join" function to do this.
viz.

```
 *select loc_id from SGTABLE where supp_text like '%?%';*

 and, i am passing "id" as a parameter.
```

I get the below error when I run.

"*Couldn't get field info from [select LOC_ID from SGTABLE WHERE SUPP_TEXT like '%?%']*"
*offending row : [ID String(5)]*

all inputs are string, and table fields are "VARCHAR".
.

I tried with "database lookup option too. But it does not have an option to match substring within a string.

Please help.

Comment: Did you check "Replace Variables"?

Answer (score 1):

The JDBC driver is not replacing the parameter within the string. You must make the wildcard string first and pass the whole thing as a parameter. Here is a quick transform I threw together that does just that:

[image]

Note that in the `Database Join` step the SQL does not have '' quotes around it. Note also that unless used properly, the `Database Join` step can be a performance killer. This however, looks to be a reasonable use of it if there are going to be a lot of different wildcard values to use (unlike in my transform).

Comment: but then, how will you pass the input field "ID" to "generate rows" ?

Comment: I'm assuming in your case you would use a `Text file input` or `CSV file input` step instead of a `Generate rows`. Note also that if you need to deal with the ID not being in the table, click the "Outer join?" checkbox and handle the resulting null in a subsequent step.

Comment: I tried the same method for a sql statement like 

select loc_id from STGTABLE where supp_text in ?


But it is not working.

How can we solve this?

Comment: IN requires a list of values. Do you know how many you have in advance or is it dynamic?

Comment: It is not dynamic. I have the set of values. Please refer to my answer below. But it is not working